# Segue Still Goes Through Despite Conditional Statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, segue

I'm new to swift and Xcode. I creating a user registration view controller and I'm using Firebase as my DB. Here is what I've written:

```
@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {

    //Register user functions

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text! , password: passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print (error!)
        } else {
            //success
            print ("Registration successful")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerToList", sender: self)
        }
    }

}
```

When a user inputs data that is incorrectly formatted, such as blank fields or improperly formatted email, my console prints out the error. However, the user is still able to bypass the registration view controller and move on to the next screen. Why is that? 
I also want to note that I'm using a Show segue - is this the issue? I can't use a push segue since it has been deprecated.

Comment: Did you hook segue from button in storyboard ?

Comment: Figured it out! That was the issue. Thanks!